# PostgreSQL or MS SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, postgresql, web-applications

I'm considering using PostgreSQL with a .Net web app. Basically 3 reasons:

1. Mature Geo Queries
2. Small footprint + Linux
3. Price

I'm wondering a bit about tools though, SQL Server Profiler and query plans and performance monitors have been helpful. How is this world with Postgres? Some other things I should consider?

Edit: Will most likely use NHibernate as ORM

Answer (score 6):

Postgres comes with pgAdmin, which does graphical explains to help you optimise queries.  Entering your query in an SQL entry pane and pressing F7 gives you a really clear indication of how the query is planned and executed.  More on this, here:

[Graphical Explain Plans](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/27-Reading-PgAdmin-Graphical-Explain-Plans.html).

If you're doing a web app and are storing or working with IP Addresses, you can use the INET data type, which allows you to store the IP Address as a real type, and do all sorts of operations on it directly - Is an IP address in banned subnet, for example.  No need to store 4 lots of quads and recombine them in code, or store it in a string.

Is running on Linux a bonus, if it's a .NET app?

Comment: I don't know about mySQL but Postgres runs a lot faster on Linux, so yes, regardless of what your front end is written in, running pg on Linux is a bonus!

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole slew of tools for PostgreSQL, some free, some not... PgAdmin + Explain ANALYZE normally will give you everything you need and it is free.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider MS SQL because of LINQ to SQL.

There is dbLinq which is still in early alpha, but it works for very simple queries.

Comment: NHibernate will most likely be the ORM choice